# Django Forms: If I use charfield in form, do I need to use clean_field?

Tags: django, django-forms

In my forms, if I have the following class with a field for my charfield 'bio'

```
class MyClass(forms.ModelForm):
    bio = forms.CharField(max_length=1000
```

Do I need to have the below validation or does the above max_length=1000 already cover that?

```
def clean_bio(self):
    bio=self.cleaned_data['bio']
    max_length = 1000
    if len(bio) > max_length:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Please limit your bio to 1000 words')
return bio
```

Comment: no,framework will do length limit for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary at all to use it for the `length`, your model field has already a `max_length`, so Django will ensure that this value has less than 1000 characters.

**NOTE**: It's suggested that you use `models.TextField()` in models since your field can receive a great length of characters. Your form will be:

```
forms.CharField(max_length=1000,widget=forms.Textarea())
```

Comment: What does TextField do that CharField doesn't? Does it give error validation if it is longer?

Comment: Nm, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354588/django-charfield-vs-textfield

Comment: In case you use it in models as well, I'm just warning you to not use it for such field. Even in form, by using `forms.CharField`, you must use the widget `forms.Textarea()`, see my updated answer