# django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(100)

Tags: python, jquery, django

I have not set `max_length` and `min_length` for `TextField`:

```
text = models.TextField(_("Full story"), null=True, blank=False)
```

But it still gives me this error:

```
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(100)
```

Could someone help please?.

Comment: maybe this link can help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354588/django-charfield-vs-textfield

i think that's not about django, but what databse you use

Comment: it is because of some other column. column `text` has nothing to do with this error.