# Can a textfield in postgres be used with a charfield in django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a table in postgres with a column `description` that had the type `varchar(2000)`, so in django:

```
description = serializers.CharField(......., max_length = 2000)
```

I want to change the `description` column in postgres to type `text`

Can I leave the `description` as a `charfield`? Or do I have to change it to a `textfield`? I still want to have `max_length` specified but change it to 5000, ie:

```
description = serializers.CharField(......., max_length = 5000)
```

I've tried to read the docs:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield, but I didn't see it being stated explicitly.

From what I've seen, it says:

```
CharField corresponds to django.db.models.fields.CharField or django.db.models.fields.TextField
```

I'm guessing that means it's ok?

I also looked around on stackoverflow:
[What's the difference between CharField and TextField in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354588/whats-the-difference-between-charfield-and-textfield-in-django), but I didn't see it being stated explicitly either.

Comment: The difference is that by default `CharField` will be presented as `Input` widget and `TextField` will be presented as `Textarea`. I use `CharField` as in most cases I want `Input` and in those case that I don't I can override the widget to be `TextArea`. In Postgres they are essentially the same thing especially as you can declare `varchar` with no length specification. See section *Tip* here [Character types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html).